# The failed() method is not being called when an Job fails in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Currently im creating a job to be queued but for some reason the `failed()` method is not being triggered when the code executed in the `handle()` method of the job throws an exception. Is this some kind of bug in Laravel or am I doing something wrong? the Queue::failing() method in my AppServiceProvider IS being called

```
  <?php
    namespace App\Jobs;

    use App\Models\Email;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class MyCommand implements ShouldQueue
    {
        use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

        protected $lead;

        /**
         * Create a new job instance.
         */
        public function __construct($lead)
        {
            $this->lead = $lead;
        }

        /**
         * Execute the job.
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            throw new \Exception("error!");
        }

        /**
         * The job failed to process.
         *
         * @param \Exception $exception
         */
        public function failed(\Exception $exception)
        {
            \Log::critical('wooot');
        }
}
```

In the above job. The failed() method is never being called. We use supervisor to keep the queue running

Thank

Comment: Which laravel version?

Comment: The laravel version is 5.4

Comment: How do you dispatch the job and how do you run it and with which driver? Also, you might want to put some logs in `src/Illuminate/Queue/FailingJob.php` and debug there..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the failed() method was being called but because of the $lead property not being public. I got an exception when I wanted to retrieve the contents of the property.